# How to get javascript function execution time using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am trying to log time to execute functions in a project. Currently i am using tracing.start method for getting the trace. But I am not able to identify of chrome devtools computes time taken by each function using the trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) directly in your project, log timings into the console and catch them by Puppeteer's [`page.on('console', ...)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-console).